# Move Multiple Files from Subfolders to Single Folder using Windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, move

I have a requirement where the files are present in folders and the subfolders. The subfolders are dynamically created with current date and time. All the files should be moved to one destination folder without the subfolders.

Folder A:

```
1.txt
2.txt
Folder 20180907-1240-008
         3.txt
         4.txt
Folder 20180907-1128-001
         5.txt
         6.txt
Folder 20180906-0040-010
         7.txt
         8.txt
```

The destination folder should look like below

Folder B:

```
   1.txt
   2.txt
   3.txt
   4.txt
   5.txt
   6.txt
   7.txt
   8.txt
```

the below command works in command prompt

```
for /r %d in (*) do copy "%d" "F:\Tickets\Movement\390558-Harmony-LCOPYREC\B
```

My batch script looks like below

```
@echo off
cd /d "A"
for /r %%d in (*) do copy "%d" "F:\Tickets\B"
```

I have an error as below while executing in a batch script

```
\Tickets\B\*
The system cannot find the file specified.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

How do I make the script working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost right, no need to CD, just specify the parent path to folder after `/r` also ensure you double quote correctly and preferbly put a backslash at the end of a path to copy to:

```
for /r "C:\path to folderA" %%d in (*) do copy "%%d" "F:\Tickets\Movement\390558-Harmony-LCOPYREC\B\"
```

if you do not want to copy all files and just `.txt` for example, simply change your criteria to `(*.txt)`

```
for /r "C:\path to folderA" %%d in (*.txt) do copy "%%d" "F:\Tickets\Movement\390558-Harmony-LCOPYREC\B\"
```

Also, not sure which path you really want as destination, but you can do:

```
@echo off
set "dest=F:\Tickets\B\"
set "source=C:\some dir\A"
for /r "%source%" %%d in (*) do copy "%%d" "%dest%"
```

Copy and paste above code is into the batch file.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following command in cmd to copy all m4a files from music folder and its all subfolder in another folder my-music. Don't forget "\" after your destination folder path.

```
for /r "c:\Users\A\Desktop\music" %x in (*.m4a) do copy "%x" "c:\Users\A\Desktop\my-music\"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from cmd then specify the parent folder path to after`/n` like `for /r "C:\parentFolderPath\" %d in (*) do copy "%d" "D:\destinationFolderPath\"` don't forget to put backslash at the end of the path.